# php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is always same domain no matter from which domain i request

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Right now for example i have this domains:

domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com

I try to use cURL from domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com **to** domain4.com and block the cURL request.

Example code file on domain1.com:

```
try{
  $ch = curl_init();
  if (FALSE === $ch){
    throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://domain4.com/test3.php?v=1.4");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $p_result = curl_exec($ch);
  var_dump($p_result);
  print_r($p_result);
  if (FALSE === $p_result) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error(), curl_errno());
    curl_close($ch);
  } else{
    curl_close($ch);
    return $p_result;
  }
}catch(Exception $e) {
  trigger_error(sprintf('Curl failed with error #%d: %s',$e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Example code file on domain4.com:

```
  $domains = array("domain1.com"); //blacklisted

  $domainIsValid = array_filter($domains, function ($var) use ($_SERVER) {
        return strpos($var, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== false;
    });

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] // is always domain1.com even if i request from domain3.com
```

Do i missing something? is it Apache server configuration?

Host: DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache server.

Comment: HTTP_HOST is “to”, not “from” ...

Comment: Than how i block "from" please advice...

Comment: If you wanted to do this based on the domain name, you would have to perform a reverse DNS lookup (of the requesting IP) first ... and that is going to be time-consuming, and will slow your site down for _every_ requesting client. Plus, as soon as you are dealing with a domain that doesn’t have its “own” IP address, but shares one with multiple other domains, even that would likely fail.

Comment: I will try to seek more, because this for example: https://github.com/wp-premium/edd-software-licensing using the same technique that i need, blocking requests for specific domain that is not listed on the database.

Comment: That seems to be doing exactly the opposite of what you are trying to do here ... this decides whether the script should run _on_ a specific domain, but I don’t see it having anything to do with where requests come from. (Are you sure you know already what exactly you actually need yourself? Right now, I’m having my doubts.)

Comment: I think i have a solution,i will try to ping back with token back and forward,for example first request will send token to domain4.com and then domain4.com check with curl request back with the token it may work.

Comment: I am trying to avoiding from people to downloading a auto-update files if they not owning a license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v finally develop a answer to my self.

The answer is to send a cURL request to the update server with the real domain HTTP_HOST in referer,
After In the update server generate a token:

```
     $token =  md5(uniqid($domain, true));//Create token
     $stmt4 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tokens (domain) VALUES (?)");//Store just to know from where the request for later use
     $stmt4->bindParam(1, $dm);
                                                // insert one row       
     $dm =  json_encode(array('domain'=>$domain,'token'=>$token),true);                    
     $stmt4->execute();
```

Then on request from domain create a file with that token that return,then check the token if found on the request domain its okay can continue update and delete the token.

```
    $exists = checkRemoteFile($domain.'/'.$token);
    if ($exists) {
        echo "found";   
    } else{
      /*  header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();*/
    }

function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically there is 2 functions,

1. Generate token with cURL request from the update server and update server return the token and create it as a file.
2. Download from server side, but before check if the token is exist and valid on request cURL domain,Token can be used only 1 time - after used delete it immediately from database of server-side.

re-generate token the same for every request and delete the token after done request.

No one can fool you with this logic.

Answer (score 1):

PHP documentation says: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
'HTTP_HOST'  Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.
```

Potentially you are sending the same headers from all domains.

I think REMOTE_ADDR or REMOTE_HOST would be more appropriate to use for blacklisting as HTTP headers can be easily spoofed.

EDIT: Note: Your web server must be configured to create REMOTE_HOST variable. For example in Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On inside httpd.conf for it to exist. See also gethostbyaddr().

Comment: I have tried now, REMOTE_HOST is empty, and REMOTE_ADDR is returning ip which is not good for me because i need only domain name block.